# A Nine letter Country

Tags: wordplay

I am a 9 letter Country.

The 2nd, 4th ,5th and 6th letters gives you a Payment.

If you take the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 7th, 8th and 9th letters I'll be part of your Eye.

Who am I?

Comment: Welcome on the Puzzling SE! As this was your first post I suggest looking at the [editing help](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for Questions / Answers as it might help you in the future :) Nevertheless I liked your question!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm looking forward to see more questions of you in the future! :) Also, if you look at the answers you get to your questions, there is a tick below the up- and downvote arrows which lets you accept an answer (in the case of the puzzling SE the correct answer to your puzzle). Accept an answer lists your question as answered on the page, so everyone can see it has already been answered correctly.

Comment: I have already acknowledged the answer with a tick mark :)

Comment: @Jishnu There isn't any answer marked as "accepted."  Can you double-check that you clicked the checkmark next to the answer?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain The click trolled me last time.I have done it and thanks for the enlightenment :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The answer is

> Argentina

It has 9 letters.

The 2nd,4th ,5th and 6th letters gives you a Payment

> rent gives you a Payment

If you set 2nd,4th,6th,7th,8th and 9th letters I'll be part of your Eye

> you get "retina"

Answer (score 1):

> Argentina it is.
>  2nd,4th,5rh and 6th forms the word rent.
>  2nd,4th,6th,7th,8th and 9th forms `retina`which is part of your eye.

Comment: This answer has already been given, also you should use spoiler tags in your answers as others may want to figure out the answer themselves.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to this platform. So i don't know about spoiler. Next time onwards i'll use spoiler.